# Trouble showing year on x-axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am using ggplot to show publications over time by year. However, my x-axis is showing up as integers (ex 2015.0) instead of each year showing up under each bar.

```
p <-ggplot(pubs, aes(x = Year, y=Pubs, fill=Author.order)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE),size=.3)
```

Comment: You need to provide a sample set of data to help us reproduce your issue. I'm guessing that Year is a numeric instead of a date. You could also try changing it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other user mentioned, it's difficult to help you without seeing your dataset, `pubs`.  With that being said, if you are seeing your axis labeled as 2015.0 for the year 2015, that definitely means `pubs$Year` is not formatted as a date.  As such, `ggplot` treats it like a normal numeric.

Try formatting as date first:

```
pubs$Year <- as.Date(pubs$Year, format="your.format.here")
```

If I saw how `pubs$Year` was constructed, I could give you a suggestion for what to use for `format=`.  By default the `as.Date` function will try different formats [according to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date) and hit you with an error if there are none found based on your data.  `as.Date` uses `strptime()` to convert into `Date` class, so you can [look at that documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime) to help understand how to write the `format=` piece.  Note that `strptime` converts characters to date types, so if your data is numeric, you may actually want to convert to character *then* convert to date.  Sounds weird, but I've done it myself because it works.  :)

There are more classes other than `Date` in R for representation of a date or date/time value, however.  You can also use `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt` using any of the `as.POSIX` functions, which [operate similarly to the `as.Date` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.POSIX*).  Any of those formats should work fine with `ggplot`.

Finally, if you want to specify anything related to the scales for representation in your plot, you can use `scale_x_date` to change breaks, limits, format labels, etc.  [See documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/scale_x_date).